# Binding object to dataset to create a report MvcReportViewer

Tags: model-view-controller, datasource, reporting

I'm trying to bind this object to a report RDLC:

```
public class DataReport
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string[] DateArray { get; set; }

    public DataReport()
    {
        this.DateArray = new string[5];
    }

}
```

I want to pass this two property to the report using MvcReportViewr ([here](https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer)). I used his example but I couldn't find the way to pass this object. I previously create the datasource and the dataset that accepts the Name and DateArray property.

As explained in the example I passed them as class as in the code below. It did not work.

```
@using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

@model DataReport

@using MvcReportViewer;
@{
ViewBag.Title = "MvcReportViewer Example";
}
  @Html.MvcReportViewerFluent("ReportData.rdlc").ProcessingMode(ProcessingMode.Local).LocalDataSource("DataSet1", Model ).Attributes(new { Height = 900, Width = 900, style = "border: none" })
```

What is the best way to pass this object to the rdlc report?